# Plot/draw signature from given points in android

Tags: android, plot

I'm trying to reconstruct a signature in a chart from given x- and y-values, which where captured before.

I've tried to plot it with Androidplot and GraphView, but the problem was that the list of x- & y-values both containing in- & decreasing values (loops in signature). So both libaries just plotted the increasing values, but refused to plot the decreasing ones. I found the Polyline.class in Android, which is drawing a line from given ordered points in google maps. Unfortunatelly I think it just works in maps.

Does anyone knows something similar to the Polyline.class, which works in a chart?

Comment: FWIW Androidplot fully supports this use case and even provides a sample implementation in the demo app (XY Scatter).  Hard to say why your attempt didn't work without seeing source but it is absolutely possible to do.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfect. I was to focused on LineGraph and didn't used the demo-app. If you add it as answer I can mark it as solved.

Comment: you got it :-) thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Androidplot fully supports this use case and even provides a sample implementation in the demo app (XY Scatter).